# JPA Hibernate - how to (REST api) POST object with foreign key as ID?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-rest

I have two entities, with one-to-many mapping. Now, I would like to add new object to database (new employee with department foreign key).

**What's the easiest way to do that?**

That's how entities looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = true)
    private Department department;
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

The goal is to pass this kind of json:

```
{
    "surname": "smith",
    "department": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fail safe strategy

- Search employee by surname: smith. If does not exist, return a json with this message: "smith user does not exist" and http status: 400 (bad request)
- Search department by id: 1. If does not exist, return a json with this message: "department does not exist" and http status: 400 (bad request)
- If the previous sentences were fine, you will have an instance of Employee and Department, ready to use

```
    Employee emp = employeeRepository.findBySurname("smith");
    //if emp does not exist, instance a new one
    Department dep = employeeRepository.findBySurname("smith");
    emp.setDepartment(dep);
    employeeRepository.save(emp);
```

- Hibernate and jpa must persist your simple entity

## Direct strategy

- Instance your employee with smith surname
- Instance your Department with id: 1
- Set your department instance in employee instance
- Execute `employeeRepository.save(emp);`
- Use a try catch to return a json message in case of error: "Internal error when employee was being persisted..."

Comment: I noticed that it also works when constructor with id is added: `public Department(Long id) {this.id = id}`. Everythong is working fine in app and database, but returned employee json looks like: {"id":1, "lastName":"bob", "department": {id and rest values are null}}